# Azure website - Select website project from solution to deploy

Tags: .net, git, azure

Is it possible to configure which web project in my solution should be used when setting up auto deploy from source control using VSO?

I have a solution containing the following projects:

- Model
- Data
- Logic
- Admin
- Public

Both the Admin and Public projects are web projects. But both web projects use all the other projects. This whole solution is in VSO git source control. So when I set up a new web site in azure and opt to connect it to source control, I don't ever get an option to select which web project is the "startup" project.

I would assume there are some options in the build definition that is created for the CD setup, but cannot find it. Am I missing a step or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about VSO but with regular git you can specify which project to deploy in [App.Settings](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#using-app-settings-instead-of-a-deployment-file). Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632955/azure-websites-deploy-specific-web-project)

A bit different scenario (push model) but the same principle - [see here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingTWOWebsitesToWindowsAzureFromOneGitRepository.aspx)