# Publishing to Azure Websites with GitHub with a single repository with multiple MVC Web Projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, github, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I have a GitHub repository with a Visual Studio Solution with the following folder structure

```
-- GitHub Repository Root Folder
-- -- Visual Studio Solution Folder
-- -- -- project-a.example.com Folder
-- -- -- project-b.example.com Folder
-- -- -- project-c.example.com Folder
```

I have three different Azure Web Sites to host these web projects projects (MVC 5 Web Application)

Looks like I can connect to a Azure Website to a single repository and can't figure out how to connect it to a sub-folder where the related project's source code reside. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure websites deploy specific web project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632955/azure-websites-deploy-specific-web-project)